# How to combine three columns into one and leave out empty cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hello I need to advice some formulas on my problem:

- How can I combine two, three or more columns into single one column?
- And if in columns are **"empty"** cells I want to skip these cells inside of that single one column.

But be aware! This is the problem. All columns are contains another formulas. So these **"empty"** cells are in fact contains my another formulas with result ="".

Here is example of what I want to get - in column E:
[image: EXAMPLE]

EDIT:

- New functions like TOCOL are not available in my Microsoft Office 365 MSO: 16.0.14326.21092 (32 bit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is not very huge use:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",1,TRANSPOSE(A2:C10))&"</s></t>","//s")
```

[image]

With VBA:

```
    Option Explicit
    
Sub To_Col()
Dim lngR As Long, lngC As Long, varV, lngRow As Long, lngCol As Long

    varV = [A2:C10]
    With ActiveCell
        lngRow = .Row
        lngCol = .Column
    End With
    For lngC = 1 To UBound(varV, 2)
        For lngR = 1 To UBound(varV)
            If varV(lngR, lngC) <> "" Then
                Cells(lngRow, lngCol).Value = varV(lngR, lngC)
                lngRow = lngRow + 1
            End If
        Next lngR
    Next lngC
    
End Sub
```

place in ***E2*** and launch macro, change `[A2:C10]` with your real range

Comment: I have huge data and your formula working only with tiny bit of range (3 cells and 45 rows).
But thank you for your try ;)

Comment: Without `TOCOL` you need VBA, I think, are you interested?

Comment: If there is no another solution except TOCOL then yes, I'm interested for some VBA script.

Comment: @Mike_BossO I've edit my post adding simply code to generate list

Comment: Thank you, your VBA is working properly ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=TOCOL(IF(A2:C10="",NA(),A2:C10),3,1)
```

---

**Note** that just `=TOCOL(A2:C10,3,1)` is not going to cut it if these cells hold an empty string `""`.

Comment: Saddly function TOCOL is not available in my version of Microsoft Office 365 MSO: 16.0.14326.21092 (32 bit).
Is there another possible solution?